# Integrating Typekit in Image Editor

Tags: android, typekit, adobecreativesdk

I have an Android application that starts Adobe Image Editor normally.

```
Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(mContext)
                    .setData(selectedImageUri)
                    .withToolList(tools)
                    .withOutput(new File(lastSavedFilePath))
                    .build();
            startActivityForResult(imageEditorIntent, 2);
```

I would like to integrate Typekit for font selection, as I see that the Aviary app automatically lets you select font from typekit when you select the "Text" tool. I can find no documentation about this. [Closest thing I can find](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/typekitui/index.html) is about adding TypeKit UI to my own activity, but that is not exactly what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't currently possible to allow users to select Typekit fonts in the Creative SDK Image Editor.

Comment: The Aviary app does it